# How can I make my @media function compatible with Device-pixel ratio

Tags: css

I had a site of two breaking points one without `@media` and the second with `@media only screen and (min-width : 600px){}` but when I try it in my phone (it is 360×640 and a device-pixel ratio of 1.5) it displays the `@media only screen and (min-width : 600px){}` part (I was expecting the none `@media` part) is it with my code maybe???

[By the way it displays the none `@media` when I change my code to `@media only screen and (min-width : 980px){}` but not even at `@media only screen and (min-width : 950px){}`]

Comment: Do you have set `<meta viewport` in html?

Comment: Thanks I had no clue  what that was, but now I have read and used it and all the problems are gone. Thank you.